# Can't find the solution with CSS styling

Tags: html, css, web

I'm coding my first more serious web design using div's and CSS styling (I'm kinda newbie in it). I had spent a lot of time to make, what I did now (about 30% of all design) and now I'm in position in which I spent a lot of time, but still didin't find the solution.

Here is image of how that part of design should look properly in all browsers: 
[image]

Here is image, of how it looks coded now in IE8 (I marked in blue wrong part):
[image]
You can see gap which shouldn't be here...

And in same time how it looks in Mozilla Firefox 9.0.1 (boxes are div'ed okey, but text don't go in place):
[image]

I think it can be something with float's because I used it in some divs.. But I don't know exactly what and how to even start searching for solution to this... So I came to Stack Overflow. Because I don't know which exactly parts of HTML and CSS to copy now, I'm uploading all the web (with images) and giving a link to check it: http://www.mediafire.com/?uf6bzly4dktummk

I hope someone can help me :s

Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: are you using a css reset? http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Comment: you may wanna try using it. load it before all other css files. this issue might only be a browser inconsistency - which a reset can fix.

Comment: Tried, noup It doesn't fix IE issue..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the gap was that mine HTML file lacked a DOCTYPE, thereby triggering Quirks Mode. My code implied the document type to be XHTML, so I added this to the top of the code, replacing the current  tag.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
```

Comment: you should go for the html5 doctype: `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Answer (score 2):

For what is wrong in FF. You have to give .texthold a fixed width, or the float won't work:

```
.texthold {
 width:97px;
}
```

Also it's better to wrap `<p></p>` around text than divs, but that's not necessary for the code to work.

Comment: Thanks, that helped for Firefox problem!

Answer (score 1):

i see the same problem in chrome as with your firefox problem. this IS a browser inconsistency. if it weren't, the bug should be the same on both IE and Firefox. try developing in chrome and add a reset.

so here's how i did it:

- remove the  `display:inline` in the following: `.meniu`, `.meniu2`, `.meniu3`, `.meniu4`, `.thumbas` and `.shadow` - you are floating them left already, no need to make them inline.
- remove `display:inline` AND `float:left` from the `.texthold` class. floating it removes it from the flow. when it exceeds the width to the right of the image, it wraps below the image. displaying them inline makes it not respect top and bottom margins. no need for a fixed width.

these solves the firefox issue. i cannot, however, figure out why IE has a spacing. nothing wrong with the DOM, they're 2 divs on top the other. there should be no space.

Comment: Thanks for checking it, I posted the IE solution as answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have use

for text section. You can remove the p tag. I think this is the reason for the gap on IE. Thanks.

Comment: What do you exactly mean? I'm not using <p>